# If-statement with NSMutableString hasprefix phone number (Beginner)

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

Hey I don't succeed to make a functional if-statement with my `NSString`

`j` is `ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)`.

I've three cases : `j=0`, `j=1`, `j=2`...

I would like that when `j = 0` or `1` or `2`, that doesn't take number with prefix **02**...

if j has number with prefix **06**, save this number.

if j has number with other prefix save it, except if number with prefix **06** is already saved.

I tried to make this code, but it doesn't work, I don't know where is my error :

```
if (j == 0) {
    if ([phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"02"]) {}
    else
        if ([phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"06"]) {
            person.number = phoneNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            if ([phoneNumber length] == 0)
            {
                person.number = phoneNumber;
            }
        }
}

if (j == 1) {
    if ([phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"02"]) {}
    else
        if ([phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"06"]) {
            person.number = phoneNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            if ([phoneNumber length] == 0)
            {
                person.number = phoneNumber;
            }
        }
}

if (j == 2) {
    if ([phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"02"]) {}
    else
        if ([phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"06"]) {
            person.number = phoneNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            if ([phoneNumber length] == 0)
            {
                person.number = phoneNumber;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the problem (it should be != instead):

```
if ([phoneNumber length] == 0)
```

To make the code simpler I would just do something like this - should be the same result:

```
if (j >= 0 && j < 3 && ![phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"02"] && (![person.number hasPrefix:@"06"] || [phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"06"])) {
    person.number = phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: just a minor typo in the last two boolean statements, you both times use `06`, one should be `02`.

Comment: maybe it is actually right, I did mis-read the difference between person.number and phoneNumber... I don't know ;)

Comment: @TiagoLira if (j >= 0 && j < 3 && (![person.number hasPrefix:@"06"] || [phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"02"])) {
                        person.number = phoneNumber;
                    } this code doesn't work, that saves number with 02

Comment: @Viny76 Sorry for being late! You are right, I didn't notice you wanted to ignore numbers with 02. It is corrected now.